# BootStrap: Why is the navbar open when when I resize to XS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a site [here](http://opteracreative.com/~baybr/about.html) using Bootstrap 3 and everything is going very well, except when I resize the screen to xs. The navigation appears, but it is extended rather than collapsed. Here is the code for the navigation:

```
<div class="row show-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Rent Now</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resident Portal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Community Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Green Living</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>  
    </ul>  
                </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Am I missing something that would cause it to be collapsed from the outset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
```

It should be:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
```

The class needed to be set to **collapsed**.